# How would I display a session alert, reload the page, and have the alert display?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, unset

I am creating a simple alert system for my PHP application, and I cannot seem to figure out why the alerts are not displaying. **I am using the MVC model for my application.**

**I am using `session_start()`!**

**Code:**

```php
    <?php
    function display_notifications(){
      $types = ['error', 'success', 'info'];
    
        foreach($types as $type) {
            if(isset($_SESSION[$type]) && !empty($_SESSION[$type])) {
                if(!is_array($_SESSION[$type])) $_SESSION[$type] = [$_SESSION[$type]];
    
                foreach($_SESSION[$type] as $message) {
                    $csstype = ($type == 'error') ? 'error' : $type;
    
                    echo '
                        <script>
                            const Toast = Swal.mixin({
                            toast: true,
                            position: "top-end",
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 3000,
                            timerProgressBar: true,
                            didOpen: (toast) => {
                                toast.addEventListener("mouseenter", Swal.stopTimer)
                                toast.addEventListener("mouseleave", Swal.resumeTimer)
                            }
                            })
    
                            Toast.fire({
                            icon: "'. $csstype .'",
                            title: "'. $message .'"
                            })
                        </script>
                    ';
                }
                unset($_SESSION[$type]);
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

I call the above function in one of my view files and then refresh the page in the controller, hoping the alert will display after the page refresh. A sample of my code that I used is below.

**index.php (view)**

```php
    <?php
    display_notifications();
    ?>
```

**IndexController (controller)**

```php
    <?php
    
    $_SESSION['success'][] = "Success!";
    refresh();
    
    ?>
```

***EDIT:*** Does the session get unset before page refresh? If so, how would I fix/improve this?

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` before you're trying to read/write from/to the sessions? If not, you need to add a `session_start()` in the beginning of your code (before any output). Without it, sessions won't be stored.

Comment: Yes, I have `session_start()` It is in my core init.php file in my application.